# Give accesskey attribute to the search box

Tags: feature-request

I had a uservoice suggestion about this :

> Give an accesskey attribute to the
>   search box so we can quickly give the
>   focus to the textbox with :
>
> - alt + shift + [accesskey] on Firefox
> - alt + [accesskey] on IE.

Sometimes I just want to quickly jump to the search box from anywhere on the page, and having accesskey property on the input tag would be the easiest way to do this.

Comment: and ctr+[accesskey] on a mac

Answer (score 2):

I have a Greasemonkey script that sets the <kbd>f</kbd> accesskey on the search box like on Wikipedia.

http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/105345

The script works on all the individual Stack Exchange sites and meta sites, http://stackexchange.com, http://data.stackexchange.com, http://area51.stackexchange.com/, all chat sites and the Stack Exchange blogs.

Unfortunately by using Greasmonkey the page has to finish loading completely before the accesskey is usable.

Comment: I updated the code slightly: http://pastebin.com/Y50h9yWR, adding in content from http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67841/ and including chat in the list of supported sites

Comment: @Yi Jiang I've updated the script on userscripts.org. I somehow missed that in most cases the search box already has an id. Using CSS instead of the unwieldy XPath API otherwise also makes things much simpler. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Yi Jiang I also put back some of the included sites as stackexchange.com, chat.stackoverflow.com, chat.meta.stackoverflow.com, and the blog sites were missing from the list.