# What's the correct way to @include all SE sites?

Tags: support, stackexchange-2.0, userscript

What's the `@include` sequence that most accurately lists all the SE sites for Greasemonkey/ userscript hacking purposes?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```txt
// All Main and Meta Stack Exchange Sites:
// @include       https://stackoverflow.com/*
// @include       https://meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @include       https://superuser.com/*
// @include       https://meta.superuser.com/*
// @include       https://serverfault.com/*
// @include       https://meta.serverfault.com/*
// @include       https://askubuntu.com/*
// @include       https://meta.askubuntu.com/*
// @include       https://mathoverflow.net/*
// @include       https://meta.mathoverflow.net/*
// @include       https://stackapps.com/*
// @include       https://*.stackexchange.com/*
//
// Exclude non-standard Stack Exchange sites & pages (eg. chat):
// @exclude       https://chat.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude       https://api.*.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude       https://data.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude       https://area51.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude       https://*/reputation
```

Comment: I'm attempting to be as future proof as possible by including upcoming sites :)

Comment: `*.stackexchange.com` includes all the metas already (and the chats as well, for that matter). The asterisk doesn't care about dots.

Comment: also, `*.stackexchange.com` will also include all future beta sites.

Comment: @alexanderpas And that's good, right?

Comment: S[OFU], Ask ubuntu, Stackapps and OnStartups are the only Stack Exchange 2.0 sites with an own domain. The other sites are not found, or redirect to the stackexchange.com domain. If you still want to stich to `@include` rules, I recommend to exclude `http://api.*.com/*` and `http://chat.*.com/*`, so that non-SE domain sites are also excluded.

Answer (score 9):

`@match` rules are [preferred](https://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/user-scripts) over `@include`, because Chrome will show "This script runs on all domains" when trying to install a Userscript in Chrome. This syntax is also compatible with both [Greasemonkey](https://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40match), and [Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#_match).

The following rules match all Stack Exchange 2.0 Q&A websites:

```txt
// @match          https://stackoverflow.com/*
// @match          https://meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match          https://superuser.com/*
// @match          https://meta.superuser.com/*
// @match          https://serverfault.com/*
// @match          https://meta.serverfault.com/*
// @match          https://askubuntu.com/*
// @match          https://meta.askubuntu.com/*
// @match          https://mathoverflow.net/*
// @match          https://meta.mathoverflow.net/*
// @match          https://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match          https://stackapps.com/*

// @exclude        https://data.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude        https://area51.stackexchange.com/*
```

Instead of adding more specific rules to disable the script for `/reputation`, `https://api.*`or `https://chat.*`, I recommend to use a simple check to filter these:

```js
if ( !/^(api|chat)\./.test(location.host) && location.pathname.indexOf('/reputation') === -1) {
    // Actual code
}
```

If you want to only target questions, use `/questions/*` at the end of each `@match` rule. In this case, there's no need to check for `api`, `chat`, `reputation`, `data` or `area51`, because `/questions/` does not exist on these subdomains.

Comment: Note: All Stack Exchange Q&A sites support the `api.` prefix. The only exception is [OnStartups](http://answers.onstartups.com): The API for this site is available at [`http://api.onstartups.stackexchange.com/`](http://api.onstartups.stackexchange.com/)