# Why does this community wiki post say it was created by a user's sockpuppet?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do old usernames stick to CW posts by design?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47474/do-old-usernames-stick-to-cw-posts-by-design)

I noticed what I thought was a funny username on [a CW post on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67842/164291):

[image: badp's sockpuppet?]

However, when I checked [the revision history for the post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/67842/revisions), I discovered that the user's username does not in fact contain the text "`'s sockpuppet`".

Where did the embellishment come from?

Comment: The user had changed their name at one point to "badp's sockpuppet" as a joke, then changed it back to "badp". Community Wiki posts aren't very good about keeping up with a users name changes, getting stuck on what the name was when the post was made/edited.

Comment: Kind of a boring reason, once you find out... good eye, though.

Comment: @gnostradamus: That's what badp wants us to believe!