# Don't ask high-rep users if they're sure they want to answer their own question

Tags: feature-request, self-answer

I've been answering a lot of my own Meta questions lately and I'm really tired of seeing this:

[image: Modal dialog: Are you sure you want to answer your own question?]

I'm a moderator and 15k rep user. I know when to answer my own question. Especially on *Meta* where self answers are particularly common.

Can this prompt please be hidden either when you have X rep or when you've been shown it Y number of times, or some combination of the two?

It's great to show it to new users, it might even be good to show a 1k rep user who's never self-answered before. But there's a point where Just in Time help turns into condescendingly assuming the user is stupid; this pop up eventually crosses that line.

Comment: Hmmm... Does the warning show if you insta-answer? Furthermore, do we need it now that we have the insta-answer thingy?

Comment: @YannisRizos no insta-answer doesn't show it, but it's a great just in time tip for new users. Not for people familiar with the system.

Comment: It might be a great just in time tip for new users, but if it's not shown on insta-answer it kinda sends mixed signals.

Comment: @YannisRizos insta-answer isn't always availible, and insta-answer doesn't have quite the same use-case...how could you use Insta Answer as a reply to other answers/comments for example?

Comment: Are you sure that you don't want to be asked about answering your own question?

Comment: @TheEstablishment shut up, Clippy

Comment: @BenBrocka, I was disappointed and slightly surprised that you didn't include a self-answer to this question. I mean, this site is *meta* after all.

Comment: @BenLee I would have, but I don't really have anything that's an "answer" to it

Comment: Do you really answer dozens of your own questions so it could bother you that much? OTOH it is useful even for high-rep user just in case you accidentally hit answer button (I know I did).

Comment: It's _extremely_ difficult to accidentally answer your own question when you have used the system long enough to accumulate 5k+ reputation points.

Answer (score 9):

Whether this suggestion is going to be approved or not, here's a user script which implements the feature (derived from the source code of an own question):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       Yes I am sure to answer my own question!
// @namespace  Rob W
// @match      https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/*
// ==/UserScript==

$("#show-editor-button input").unbind('click').click(function () {
    $("#show-editor-button").hide();
    $("#post-form").removeClass("dno");
    StackExchange.editor.finallyInit();
});
```

Add additional `@match` rules if you want to add the feature to more sites ([full list of `@match` rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123683/169101?whats-the-correct-way-to-include-all-se-sites)).

### Chrome version

In Google chrome, user scripts are converted to Content scripts, which cannot access the page's non-DOM methods directly. To get it to work, use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879/938089?building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       Yes I am sure to answer my own question (Chrome version)!
// @namespace  Rob W
// @match      https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/*
// ==/UserScript==

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.textContent = '(' + function() {    
    $("#show-editor-button input").unbind('click').click(function() {
        $("#show-editor-button").hide();
        $("#post-form").removeClass("dno");
        StackExchange.editor.finallyInit();
    });
} + ')();';
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
script.parentNode.removeChild(script);
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally, if I have resorted to answering my own question, that means either

1. There are no answers
2. None of the present answers are sufficient.

In either of those cases, "Answer your own question" is the only real option.

It is impossible for an experienced user to mistake the "answer your own" button for the "add a comment" button. This means that the alert does not deter unwanted behavior (as this cannot be mistaken by an experienced user and answering one's own question is the *desired* behavior in these cases), and it *does* make the desired behavior more difficult.

Comment: Impossible it is? Only the sith in absolutes deal. Be weary, you must!

Comment: @ryan How do you know I'm not a Sith?