# Disable "Are you sure you want to answer" box in certain situations

Tags: feature-request, answers

**EDIT**: *Please, consider the fact that this question is **not** a duplicate of [that one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133759/189165). It is an 11-years later re-post. The fact that there is the same eleven years old question gives me nothing. The fact that you mark current question as duplicate also gives me nothing. I want that feature. After eleven years and 52 upvotes nothings has changed, so I am reposting. Thanks for your understanding.*

---

I am at 10k+ rep (on some sites) and I've been around here for about 10+ years. I've seen the below popup box "million of times".  I think I am aware of the difference between SE and a regular forum, and between commenting, answering and editing questions.

Can you, please, stop nagging me with this dully box?

[image: popup message: "Are you sure you want to answer your question? Comment if you're trying to respond to an answer. Edit your question if you need to add more details"]

Can we have some feature, filter or whatever that will take me directly into writing my answer and will not require me to click *Yes, I want to post an answer* for the thousandth time in my life, based on some stats, i.e.:

- Been here for couple of years
- Has a certain rep
- Seen and clicked this damn box hundreds of times.

Or I don't know.

**EDIT**: [emotional-part] *After all these years spent here, SE still thinks that I am a moron that can't tell the difference between answering my own question and asking a follow-up question. And thus, shows me this irritating popup* [/emotional-part].

In the same time it does not think that I am a moron and it assumes that I **do know** this difference, because when I click *Answer your own question* checkbox while asking a question in the first place, no such popup is seen.

Comment: How often *do* you self answer to see it millions of times?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Did you notice that "million" was given in quotation? Intentionally. I've seen this enough times. SE encourages us into sharing knowledge in Q&A style and yet shoots me with such weird nag... way too much. Or maybe let's put that opposite way: What is the reason behind seeing this more than 10 times? Or still seeing this after 10 years? Even, if I am answering my eleventh question?

Comment: Does that dialog pop up if you tick the "Answer your own question" box?

Comment: Are you suggesting the behavior of *all* those popups be changed? There's a bigger chance you might forget you answered a question already, so that popup may be useful. The one that prompts when there are 30 answers already might also still be useful.

Comment: @Laurel Nope, I am asking about removing (changing behaviour) of this single popup that is depicted in my question. And only in certain situations that Is also listed in my question. Plus: scenarios in which you are answering the same question for the _second_ time are hundreds (if not thousands) times less frequent then situations when you are answering something for the _first_ time. Saving the first situation is not worth annoying so many users so many times that they see this nag.

Comment: @Laurel Plus, I might be too emotional or too serious, but I find this popup offending. SE is all about sharing knowledge and is encouraging me into sharing it in form of questions **and** answers. When I am trying to do so, it hit my face with the closing doors with a label on it suggesting that I may be too stupid to make a difference between answering my question and asking a follow up question. After all these years spent here I **do know** the difference between Q&A site and a forum and I don't have to be reminded this each and every time I am... trying to share knowledge in Q&A format.

Comment: @PM2Ring It would be easier to click "Ask a question" here and stumble upon that checkbox than asking this in comment, right? :) :) :) Nope, no such popup in this case. When you check the _Answer your own question_ checkbox, you are directly presented with another edit box. For providing both your question and answer in one go. Thanks for this, I'll update my question here, because this seems a very good reason.

Comment: @ElementsinSpace Wooooow! Windows XP! Wooooow! Asked 10 years ago and still nothing. To be honest, I am not sure, what I should do? This truly does answer my question (so mine here is a duplicate), but I was always told, that if there is no effect since asking for something since 5+ years then we're legitimate to post a duplicate to "restart" the topic.

Comment: Since there is a [checkbox for people who want to self-answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lcx2X.png) when they write the question the *nag* is a reminder that you were the one who asked the question, as so can accept your own answer. --- While it might annoy you the purpose is that someone is helped. You go from asking that it be reputation based, to saying "or I don't know".

Comment: Do you want reputation, a profile setting, maybe a checkbox 'Don't show this message again' - It helps to offer a specific solution or list of choices; also how it's an improvement for everyone. --- Even I get nagged to review my question before submitting, it actually doesn't help as much as I'd hope for; I must submit before the improvements become glaringly obvious. ;) --- It is OK to re-ask after a few years.

Comment: @Rob I think I missing the whole idea of feature-request. I was more than sure that we (users, the community) are only proposing so solution (business requirements) and technical details (technical and business analysis) is up to the development team. If you're asking me, I'd say that since we see this nag when we are answering our own question then there must be either a checkbox "I understand, don't show this anymore" or there should be a counter for... let's say... if I have already answered... let's... 10 or 25 of my own questions then don't show this anymore.

Comment: @Rob It "It is OK to re-ask after a few years" then should be keep an opening nag here that this question is a duplicate?

Comment: You can see how I voted, but others disagreed. See the FAQ for advice on reopening.